# OpenSSL in web service hosted in Azure

Tags: azure, openssl

I'm looking to host a web service in Azure that executes OpenSSL commands via command shell: such as: "openssl smime -sign..."

Do the App Services have it installed?  Do I need to spin up a VM instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a new Linux App service and the installed version of OpenSSL is 1.0.2p.  You can also deploy your app in a container for greater control of the tool you need.

Comment: You're a champion.  Thank you Sir.